# After editing .htacess for redirect some users started get the validation error on node creation page. What do I need to do?

Tags: 6, redirection, .htaccess, sessions

I put the following code in my .htaccess to redirect the URL with www to the one without.

```
  # To redirect all users to access the site WITH the 'www.' prefix,
    # (http://www.example.com/... will be redirected to http://example.com/...)
    # adapt and uncomment the following:
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

The redirect works correctly. However now some users start reporting me that they get the following error on node creation when they try to save the node.

```
Validation error, please try again. If this error persists, please contact the site administrator.
```

After reading [the answer to this quetion](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/6500/validation-error-please-try-again-if-this-error-persists-please-contact-the-s) I'm guessing it's a session issue. (Please correct me if I'm wrong).

My question is do I need to add something else in .htaccess along with the code above?

Comment: Are you setting the base url and the cookie domain in your settings.php?  If so, make sure they don't have the www.

Comment: No I haven't done anything with settings.php. Do I need to set cookie domain in .htaccess?